# Winding coils in an AC generator

Tags: ac, electromagnetism, generator, coil, electromagnetic

Assume a coil arrangement in an AC generator like the one seen below:

[image]

Given that the magnet has one pole on each side (2 poles in total in the magnet), how must the surrounding coils be wound? In order to achieve a combined voltage, should opposite coils be wound in the opposite direction or in the same direction?

Comment: You want NSNS and use the Right Hand Rule.  Wrap fingers around coil in direction of conventional current and thumb points to North pole.

Comment: What magnet do you refer to and where did the picture come from?

Comment: @Andyaka The magnet is in the middle of the diagram, between the coils. It would be rotating between these coils to induce current.